# The \smallsmile and \smallfrown commands render identically to \smile and \frown

Tags: bug, mathjax

In MathJax it seems that `\smallsmile` and `\smallfrown` render identically to `\smile` and `\frown` respectively (on my computer at least). If other people confirm this issue I'll submit a bug report to the MathJax maintainers.

Consider the code

```
$$\begin{array}{cc}  
\smallsmile & \smallfrown\\
\smile & \frown
\end{array}$$
```

Here it is *as rendered by the site* (this is not a screenshot):
$$\begin{array}{cc}  
\smallsmile & \smallfrown\\
\smile & \frown
\end{array}$$
Here it is *as I see it in Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m* (zoomed in 250%):

[image]

Here it is *as I see it in Internet Explorer 10.0.9200.16540* (zoomed in 250%):

[image]

Here it is *as I see it when compiling it in my LaTeX editor* (zoomed in 250%):

[image]

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Comment: If I may not-so-humbly suggest, can this question (or its general structure) be listed somewhere official as the desired format for all reports of "this formatting looks weird"?

Comment: Did the fact that the `\smallfrown` and the `\frown` look the same made you `\frown` or just a `\smallfrown`? Or maybe it actually made you `\smile`? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in MathJax's font data table.  The small frown should be a "variant form" that is taken from a different font from the larger form.  Currently however, they both produce the same character in the same font.  This will be fixed in the next release of MathJax. Thanks for reporting the problem.  I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/436) for this on the MathJax GitHub site.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Davide!

Comment: Note:  this has been fixed in v2.2-beta of MathJax.  Since MSE uses that version, you should see the correct rendering in Zev's first example above.